# Not able to get the Device information in IBM Mobile first console with IONIC + MFP App

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am working with integrating IBM Mobile first with my Ionic App. In there i have added a call for a IBM server connectivity.

In there i can able to Connect my App with their server. In my console i can able see like, the sever was get connected.

My issue is,
  In mobile first Operation console, i am not able to get any information regarding to my App.
(i.e) Device information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
I took your app from GitHub and did the following:

1. from the root folder of the project, ran the command: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp`
2. Added the following code inside app.js -> `window.MFPClientDefer.promise.then(function wlCommonInit(){`:

   ```
   WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then(
       function () {       
           alert ("successfully obtained a token from the server");
       },
       function(response) {
                   alert("Unable to obtain a token from the server: " + JSON.stringify(response));
       }
   );
   ```
3. Ran the command: `ionic build android`
4. Ran the command: `ionic emulate android`

I could then see the app in the Devices view ("TestIBM"):

[image]

**Original answer:**
If your application truly successfully connected to the server (that is, it is correctly registered and has obtained a token), you will see it in the Devices view in the Operations Console, or in the Apps view in the Analytics Console.

For example:

[image]

Comment: I have added my sample app in github,
      https://github.com/Smohanapriya/mobilefirst
Can you suggest us how to confirm whether our app is connected with mobile first server 8.0.0 or not. Because this problem is only with real devices.In emulator it is working fine which mean i can able to see the emulator device details over there. That's what we get confused.

Comment: @Priya, you have simply not followed any of the instructions you were given. See my updated answer.

Comment: Its working fine for me After using obtainAccessToken(). Our Issues is with IP address.Thank you.

Comment: Working sample https://github.com/Smohanapriya/ionic-with-mobilefirst-8.0.0-beta-Sample