# Unable to connect to MobileFirst Server 8 beta

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on ionic with mobilefirst project. While i am trying to integrate ionic App with mobile first, the mobilefirst server is not connecting with my App, in the server console i am not getting any information regarding to my App.

Configuration:

- mobilefirst: 8.0.0
- cordova: 6.1.1
- android: 5.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To first step in order to have the MobileFirst Server recognize your application is **to register the application**. You can do this in two ways:

1. Using the MobileFirst CLI

   - Make sure you have the CLI installed
   - navigate to the root folder of the application project
   - Run the command: `mfpdev app register`
2. Directly from the MobileFirst Console.
   This step will require you to manually enter the details of your application

   - Load the console, typically localhost:9080/mfpconsole (if running the server locally)
   - Next to "Applications" in the sidebar navigation click on "New"
   - Provide the app details:
   - Name
   - Platform
   - bundle ID and version (you can find these in the config.xml file of your application project

The next step is to actually have the application send a request to the server to see if the connection succeeded...

Add the SDK by running the command: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp`

Open the index.js file of your application and add the following code (just an example):

```
function wlCommonInit() {
    WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then(
        function () {       
            alert ("successfully obtained a token from the server");
        },
        function(response) {
                    alert("Unable to obtain a token from the server: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    );
}
```

Take a look at this Ionic example: https://github.com/csantanapr/mfp8-ionic-demo/blob/master/www/js/app.js

Once the custom "MFP init" has been fired, you can then use the above `WLAuthorizationManager` API.

If it fails, then you did not properly register your application.

- Make sure the version is correct
- Make sure the bundle name is correct

Please read through the tutorials: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/all-tutorials/

You can also find Ioic app examples with MFP, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/labs/developers/8.0/intro/

Comment: Thank u Idan.
 I have done all the steps.Then in ionic i have added & tested with your given code in app.js file. I getting some error in console as,

wlclient init started
worklight.js:5090 before: initOptions.onSuccess
 worklight.js:5090 Connected
 worklight.js:5090 after: initOptions.onSuccess
 worklight.js:5090 wlclient init success
 worklight.js:5090 getCachedAccessToken for scope  failed: undefined

Comment: You must execute MFP APIs inside `wlCommonInit() {  ...  }`

Comment: This is the factory which we are using...

window.MFPClientDefer = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$q').defer();;
window.wlCommonInit = window.MFPClientDefer.resolve;
window.MFPClientDefer.promise.then(function wlCommonInit(){
   WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken().then(
        function () {
            alert ("successfully obtained a token from the server");
        },
        function(response) {
                    alert("Unable to obtain a token from the server: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    );
  mfpMagicPreviewSetup();
 });

Comment: Try again, with only wlCommonInit, in index.js. If it works, then open a new question and direct it at the Ionic community and not MFP.

Comment: app.js file is the base for ionic app. There is no index.js file. we are just trying to implement mfp features in ionic app with angularjs.That i have already mentioned in my question.

Comment: Follow the lab examples: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/labs/developers/8.0/intro/

Comment: As well as this video: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/04/11/getting-started-with-ionic-and-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-8-0/

Comment: Now i can able to see device details in mfpserver by running my app using emulator (Geny Motion).
The command what i was used is "ionic run android --livereload" .
But i not able to see those device details while running my app with the real device.
I have attached my sample project in the following github path,
https://github.com/Smohanapriya/mobilefirst

Comment: You already asked that question, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139441/not-able-to-get-the-device-information-in-ibm-mobile-first-console-with-ionic

Comment: Working Sample,
https://github.com/Smohanapriya/ionic-with-mobilefirst-8.0.0-beta-Sample

Comment: suddently, today i am not able to connect with mfpserver using your same above function.can you provide me your solution?

Comment: You have likely updated either your client side SDK but did not update the server, or updated your server but did not update your SDK...

Comment: I have tried to install mfpdev cli using npm command & also developer kit. but i am not able to download the latest developer kit from the https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/

Comment: Idan, I have updated client SDK. Can you provide me the link to update mfp server?

Comment: The download is not available. For now you can use the Mobile Foundation Bluemix service.